# String Manipulation Inconsistency

Tags: vb.net, string, stringbuilder

This is a more general question. I am reading a document and saving its contents into a string variable. The resulting variable contains approximately 1 million characters (no cleansing). My code would then search the string, and extract key words. However, I am hung-up on an issue:

If I pass the string directly to a message box, it will show me the contents using Mid:

```
Messagebox.Show(Mid(searchString, startPos, endPos))
```

However, if I first pass the mid to a string variable, the contents are empty and the messagebox displays nothing:

```
Dim myString as String
myString = Mid(searchString, startPos, endPos)
Messagebox.Show(myString)
```

The same effect happens when I use .substring and when I use a stringbuilder.

Does anybody know why this is happening? I assume something is happening during assignment, but I am not sure what is lost?

Here is a snippet of code:

```
    searchPos = textString.IndexOf(searchText, searchPos, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

    MessageBox.Show(searchPos)

    MessageBox.Show(Mid(textString, searchPos, 100))
```

So, the inconsistency is as such: the length of textString is around 3,700,000 characters. When I find the indexOf, the value returned in the first Messagebox is 455,225. However, if I try to pull out the characters using Mid, the second messagebox is blank.

Also, although it claims to be 3,700,000 characters, if I do a messagebox on textString, I am only shown around 6 characters of what appears to be XML. The file that is being searched is an old .ppt file, and I know I can just work-around it, but I am confused by how the computer can find the indexof my searchText correctly, but then cannot show me anything.

Thoughts?

Comment: The two should produce equivalent results.  When you run the problematic version under the debugger, what values does it show for the parameters?

Comment: Where is this code?  I agree with jdigital, it should produce the same result so long as the three variables are the same when tested.

Comment: Tested in Visual Studio 2010 Express, both ways work. What version are you using?

Comment: This is the kind of thing that happens when you completely ignore the fact that a .ppt file is a *binary* file, not a text file.  Whatever you read will contain zeros.  MessageBox is a C function under the hood, it stops displaying text when it encounters a zero.  You must use the classes in the Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint namespace instead.